# Estimate error of $\int_0^{1/2} \exp(-x^3)\, dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Estimate within an error of at most $0.001$:

$$\int_0^{1/2} \exp(-x^3)\, dx$$

I am not sure if using Taylor Series is the best way to do this. Is there not a formula for estimating error of such an integral?

Comment: Are you using any particular numerical method?

Comment: Yes, I think using Taylor Series and the Lagrange Remainder might be appropriate. At x = 0, this integral results in 1-x^3+x^6/2-x^9/6+x^12/24 etc.

Comment: Are you sure it is not any of Simpson's, Newton-Cotes, Gaussian, Monte-Carlo...?

Comment: I think using Taylor's makes sense, although perhaps Simpson's also makes sense. What are your thoughts?

Comment: It depends what class this is for, but Simpson's and Newton-Cotes will certainly work and make more sense.

Comment: How would you go about using Simpson's to find the error?

Comment: http://math.cmu.edu/~mittal/Recitation_notes.pdf (even better)

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many, way to accurately estimate the value of integrals such as this. Deciding which method is "best" requires us to select a particular goal and measure of cost.

Suppose that the goal is to obtain the answer with an relative error comparable to the round off error in double precision and the smallest possible number of arithmetic operations. What can be done?

Starting with the a generic approach we pull out the trapezoidal rule and obtain the following results

```
       k    Th                   Fh               Eh
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       0    0.4706242256461489   0.00000000e+00   0.0000000000000000e+00 
       1    0.4814362220744265   0.00000000e+00   3.6039988094258937e-03 
       2    0.4840532035985640   4.13147603e+00   8.7232717471247279e-04 
       3    0.4847015565754532   4.03635306e+00   2.1611765896306645e-04 
       4    0.4848632714480290   4.00923531e+00   5.3904957525293305e-05 
       5    0.4849036767589022   4.00231725e+00   1.3468436957708718e-05 
       6    0.4849137766225767   4.00057983e+00   3.3666212248539829e-06 
       7    0.4849163014969755   4.00014499e+00   8.4162479957461400e-07 
       8    0.4849169327098551   4.00003625e+00   2.1040429321050880e-07 
       9    0.4849170905127176   4.00000906e+00   5.2600954184948513e-08 
      10    0.4849171299634106   4.00000230e+00   1.3150230978216845e-08 
      11    0.4849171398260821   4.00000068e+00   3.2875571894426989e-09 
      12    0.4849171422917498   4.00000036e+00   8.2188922334580639e-10 
      13    0.4849171429081658   4.00000576e+00   2.0547200977697835e-10 
      14    0.4849171430622721   3.99994092e+00   5.1368761096644753e-11 
      15    0.4849171431007973   4.00014985e+00   1.2841709177517183e-11 
      16    0.4849171431104297   3.99951015e+00   3.2108204983671840e-12 
      17    0.4849171431128402   3.99601603e+00   8.0350541035537993e-13 
      18    0.4849171431134378   4.03418803e+00   1.9917401061775308e-13 
      19    0.4849171431135893   3.94285714e+00   5.0515147620444623e-14 
      20    0.4849171431136335   3.42964824e+00   1.4728958793360409e-14 
      21    0.4849171431136123  -2.08376963e+00  -7.0684199234468297e-15 
      22    0.4849171431136462  -6.25204583e-01   1.1305771134099510e-14 
      23    0.4849171431136058  -8.39285714e-01  -1.3470706032118565e-14
```

Here $N=2^k$ is the number of subintervals, $T_h$ is the trapezoidal sum corresponding to the stepsize $h = h_0/N$ where $h_0 = \frac{1}{2}$. The third column lists Richardson's fraction
\begin{equation}
F_h = \frac{T_{2h} - T_{4h}}{T_h - T_{2h}}
\end{equation}
which in exact arithmetic would tend (monotonically) to 4. The fourth column is Richardson's error estimate
\begin{equation}
E_h = \frac{T_h - T_{2h}}{3}.
\end{equation}
The computed values of $F_h$ behave as they would had they been computed in exact arithmetic until $k=11$. They continue to decay monotonically until $k=12$, but the speed is wrong. The quality of the computed error estimate is likely to decay for $k>11$. At $k=11$ our error estimate is roughly $3.28 \cdot 10^{-8}$. We are far from having exhausted double precision accuracy, so we do one step of Richardson extrapolation and obtain
\begin{equation}
A_h = T_h + \frac{T_h - T_{2h}}{3} \approx 4.849171431136415 \cdot 10^{-1}
\end{equation}
which is almost certainly as good as it is going to get. However, we have lost our error estimate and while a new one could be obtained easily, we should pause and consider the cost that we have paid until now. We have done $2^{11}+1$ function evaluations of the form $y = \exp(-x^3)$. They are certainly not free, but numerical integration has one saving grace: it is massively parallel and as many as $2^{11}+1$ processing units could work on this problem. However, in terms of the number of arithmetic operations the path through the trapezoidal rule with constant step size is expensive.

As suggested by user3832862 this problem challenges the student to apply Taylor's formula. The Taylor series converges uniformly on the interval and we can integrate the series term by term. We have
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \exp(-x^3) dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{x^{3k}}{k!} dx = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k! (3k+1) 2^{3k+1}}.
\end{equation}
We notice that not only is the series alternating, but the terms decay extremely rapidly. In fact for $k=10$ the (relative) error is already smaller the double precision roundoff error and at a mere fraction of the total number of arithmetic operations. However, we have now used a very problem specific approach, which is serial in nature, and we still have to take round off errors into account. This is also doable, but a question for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Pencil and paper solution only:

Using the power series expansion of $\exp$:
$$I=\int_0^{1/2}\mathrm{e}^{-x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_0^{1/2}\frac{(-x)^{3n}}{n!}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{3n+1}(3n+1)n!}.$$
Denote by $(S_N)_N$ and $(R_N)_N$ the sequences of partial sums and remainders of this series, namely:
$$\forall N\in\mathbb{N},\ S_N=\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{3n+1}(3n+1)n!}\qquad\text{and}\qquad R_N=\sum_{n=N+1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{3n+1}(3n+1)n!}.$$
Of course, for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $I=S_N+R_N$.

Now, the series we obtained for $I$ is an alternating series and since the sequence
$$\left(\frac1{2^{3n+1}(3n+1)n!}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$
is decreasing, we have:
$$\forall N\in\mathbb{N},\ \lvert R_N\rvert\leq\frac1{2^{3N+4}(3N+4)(N+1)!}$$
(the absolute value of the remainder of the alternating series is non-greater than that of its first term). So it's enough to find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\frac1{2^{3N+4}(3N+4)(N+1)!}<0.001.$$
Taking $N=1$ works. In fact,
$$\lvert R_1\rvert\leq\frac1{2^77(2)!}=\frac1{2^87}<0.0006.$$
Also, using the fact that the sign of the remainder is that of its first term, which for $N=1$ is positive,
$$0\leq R_1<0.0006.$$
Now,
$$S_1=\frac12-\frac1{2^44}=\frac{31}{64},$$
Hence
$$\frac{31}{64}\leq I=S_1+R_1<\frac{31}{64}+0.0006.$$
By a straightforward long division, we obtain:
$$0.484<\frac{31}{64}<0.48438+0.0006=0.48498,$$
hence
$$0.484<I<0.48498.$$
(I purposely kept a few extra digits for the upper bound in order to have the value of $I$ correct to 3 decimal places: $I=0.484\ldots$).